# Extract substring from a string using sub pattern in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Suppose i have a line of text in a column :

"Flow ""DIT-Start-Auto Generate Incidents"" launched in DF Operations.
See <https://ovb75gh.xyz.com:8443/PAS/app? INC3294144 service=RCLinkService/ReportLinkDispatch&sp=SINDIVIDUAL_REPAIR_LEVEL&sp=S96e6631e-3678-4033-b41b-5b9d99d13656&sp=l0&sp=l11778203235&sp=l11836203295>"

from the above text i want to extract only the INC3294144 using pattern INC where the remaining part after INC (3294144) is dynamic and changes with scenarios.

Comment: Did any of our responses answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query, you can create a new custom column using this below code-

```
Text.Start( Text.Range([your_column_name],Text.PositionOf([your_column_name],"INC")),Text.PositionOf(Text.Range([your_column_name],Text.PositionOf([your_column_name],"INC"))," "))
```

to return null if there is no INC in the text, use this below-

```
if Text.PositionOf([your_column_name],"INC") = -1 then
null
else
Text.Start( Text.Range([your_column_name],Text.PositionOf([your_column_name],"INC")),Text.PositionOf(Text.Range([your_column_name],Text.PositionOf([your_column_name],"INC"))," "))
```

Output will be something like below-

[image]

Comment: and what if i want to return null value if nothing with INC is found.

Comment: use if condition and return null when the PositionOf "INC" return null

Comment: @TathagataBaisya please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple Text.BetweenDelimiters should work here:

```
Text.BetweenDelimiters([TextCol], "app? ", " service=")
```

This will return an empty string if there is no match.

This does, of course, depend on these delimiters being present and it's possible you may want a less strict matching condition like this (which still makes some assumptions that might not hold in your particular case):

```
Text.BetweenDelimiters([TextCol], "? ", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your question if all the data is one cell that you are checking?

If so you can use a custom column that checks a column named **a**

```
= try Text.Middle([a],Text.PositionOf([a],"INC"),Text.PositionOf(Text.Middle([a],Text.PositionOf([a],"INC"),999)," ")) otherwise null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use regular expressions

- Paste this code into a blank query:

```
//see http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
// and https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf

let   fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
fx
```

- rename it with a useful name:  I used `fnRegex`
- Then you can use M-Code like this to add a custom column using the Regex pattern seen below

```
   #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "INC", each fnRegex([Column1], "INC[0-9]+"))
```